# How does .Net binds DBContext to specific database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, dbcontext

I am learning EF Code first approach and followed this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj193542. When the application was run for the first time, it created a database in C:\Users\User123\ directory and added records to Blogs table. Then I commented the code to add records to database and it properly retrieved records.

Then I thought to move the database into a folder under project, so I cut it from C:\Users to a folder named Data in the project, and added a connection string in app.config and used name of connectionstring in BloggingContext constructor like this

```
public BloggingContext () : base("MyConnection")
```

Here is the connection string:

```
name="MyConnection"

providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf; Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

But when I ran the application it said failed to connect. So:

Question 1: Is this not a correct connection string?

Then I deleted the database from the project thinking that BloggingContext would re-create the database. But to my surprise, it did not create database this time. However, if I change the db context name from BloggingContext to BloggingContext_New (or some other), it created the database again.

Everytime I put a new name it created a new database, but when I put BloggingContext, it does not create DB. So, I have another question

Question 2: Where does .Net keep association of DBCOntext to DB and is there any way to find/edit or delete this, so that I can re-create a DB with same name as previous one?

Thanks a lot for reading through the long question.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Is this not a correct connection string?

This is Correct.

> Question 2: Where does .Net keep association of DBCOntext to DB and is there any way to find/edit or delete this, so that I can re-create a DB with same name as previous one?

You need to make sure following to re-created a DB with same name

> 1. First go to Server Explorer in Visual Studio, check if the ".mdf" Data Connections for this project are connected, if so, right click and delete.
> 2. Go to Solution Explorer, click show All Files icon.
> 3. Go to App_Data, right click and delete all ".mdf" files for this project.

(And make sure to remove all *migration* related folders and files, if you used migration)

Answer (score 0):

When you say you moved it to a folder named data, do you mean you created a folder called data and put it there?
The |DataDirectory| part in the connection string refers specifically to the app_data folder that exists in the web projects. If you don't have one you need to right mouse click the web project and choose add -> ASP.NET folder and choose App_Data. 
Whenever this type of problem occurs it's almost always a permissions issue. Just be careful when you deploy this site to a hosted provider (e.g. Azure) the IIS process won't have write access to this folder so it's best to include the database in the project once you've created it. You can do this by clicking the show all files icon at the top of the solution explorer,  expanding the app_data folder and right mouse clicking the .mdf / .sdf and selecting include in project

Comment: *it's best to include the database in the project once you've created it.* . By this, you mean, just to make sure that database is placed in App_data folder? or there is some other action required to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Is this not a correct connection string?

If you have your database file in your project structure it will recreate the file in the debug folder when you build/rebuild.

Thats why when you delete the file from the output compilation folder manually, it will result  in connection erros if you run the program without building again.

The connection string is ok.

> Question 2: Where does .Net keep association of DBCOntext to DB and is
>   there any way to find/edit or delete this, so that I can re-create a
>   DB with same name as previous one?

You need to tell DbContext your strategy for managing the DB file if you want custom behavior.

For instance, we use the following code in one of our systems, that drops and creates the database everytime the applications starts up:

```
    static EntityContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EntityContext>(new DbInitializer());
        using (EntityContext db = new EntityContext())
            db.Database.Initialize(false);
    }

    class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EntityContext>
    {
    }
```

And for the association, if you do not define the connection string for DbContext, it will use the one defined in the app.config.

Hope it helps.